# How to pass enumeration type to a function

Tags: scala

I have an enumeration

```
object UserTokenType extends Enumeration {
  type TokenType = Value
  val RegistrationConfirmation = Value("RegistrationConfirmation")
  val ResetPasswordConfirmation = Value("ResetPasswordConfirmation")
}
```

I want to pass it to a function like this

```
def generateEmailTokenForUser(user:User,tokenType:UserTokenType) = {..}
```

But the above doesn't compile.

Do I need to pass it as Int? My concern is how to check that a valid enumeration value has been passed?

Comment: You use `UserTokenType.Value` or `UserTokenType.UserTokenType`

Comment: also you can create `sealed trait UserTokenType` and `case object RegistrationConfirmation extends UserTokenType`. This solution is better for pattern matching, because sbt can warn you in compile time if you miss some case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to keep your original method signature try the following

```
object UserTokenType extends Enumeration {
  type UserTokenType = Value
  val RegistrationConfirmation = Value("RegistrationConfirmation")
  val ResetPasswordConfirmation = Value("ResetPasswordConfirmation")
}
import UserTokenType._

def generateEmailTokenForUser(tokenType: UserTokenType) = ???
generateEmailTokenForUser(RegistrationConfirmation)
```

where we changed the type alias to

```
type UserTokenType = Value
```

and then brought it in scope with

```
import UserTokenType._
```

As an alternative consider [enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum)

```
import enumeratum._

sealed trait UserTokenType extends EnumEntry

object UserTokenType extends Enum[UserTokenType] {
  val values = findValues
  case object RegistrationConfirmation extends UserTokenType
  case object ResetPasswordConfirmation extends UserTokenType
}
import UserTokenType._

def generateEmailTokenForUser(tokenType: UserTokenType) = tokenType
generateEmailTokenForUser(RegistrationConfirmation)
```

---

As a side note, consider the difference between the type of the singleton object and singleton object as value

```
val x:         Int        =      42
val y: UserTokenType.type = UserTokenType
                |                 |
               type             value
```

so when you wrote

```
def generateEmailTokenForUser(tokenType: UserTokenType)
```

that is similar in principle to

```
def f(x: 42)
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comment, you can use the `Value` which is a class defined within [Enumeration](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/Enumeration.html) (please see linked docs). You cannot use the `UserToken` directly here because it's not a class or type (and so it's misleading to call it so).

Example of working code:

```scala
object UserToken extends Enumeration {
  val RegistrationConfirmation = Value("RegistrationConfirmation")
  val ResetPasswordConfirmation = Value("ResetPasswordConfirmation")
}


val v:UserToken.Value = UserToken.ResetPasswordConfirmation

def generateEmailTokenForUser(user:User, token:UserToken.Value) = {
  token match {
    case UserToken.RegistrationConfirmation => println("case 1")
    case UserToken.ResetPasswordConfirmation => println("case 2")
  }
}
```